# Doctrine2 / SQL cooccurrences query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I actually want to write a Doctrine query (using the query builder), but first I want the SQL query. The query should retrieve **the cooccurrences between the countries**. In other words, I want to know **how many times the country X collaborated with the country Y**. FYI, a **collaboration is when two (or more) inventors from different countries belong to the same patent**.

This is my schema :

The **Country** class:

```
namespace Db\CreatorBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Db\CreatorBundle\Entity\Inventor;

/**
 * Country
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Inventor", mappedBy="country")
     */
    private $inventors;
}
```

The **Patent** class:

```
namespace Db\CreatorBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Db\CreatorBundle\Entity\Country;

/**
 * Inventor
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Db\CreatorBundle\Entity\InventorRepository")
 */
class Inventor
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="fullName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fullName;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Patent", mappedBy="inventors")
    */
    private $patents;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Country", inversedBy="inventors")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_code", referencedColumnName="code")
     */
    private $country;

}
```

I have already written the query that retrieves the cooccurrences between the inventors, now I need the one for the countries.

So the result should be something like this :

```
Country | Country   | Number of cooccurrences
US      | FR        | 30
US      | KR        | 12
US      | JP        | 91
CA      | AU        | 40
FR      | AU        | 23
FR      | NL        | 5
```

Oh, and thank you !

**EDIT #1**

This is my first query :

```
SELECT a.inventor_id, b.inventor_id, count(*) cnt
FROM inventors_patents a INNER JOIN inventors_patents b ON b.patent_id = a.patent_id
AND b.inventor_id > a.inventor_id 
GROUP BY a.inventor_id, b.inventor_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

The result looks like this :

```
AU1 AU2 8
AU1 AU3 7 
AU1 AU4 7
AU2 AU3 6
AU2 AU5 4
AU3 AU6 3
```

Comment: Take a look at **EDIT#1**

Comment: Well, what is the problem ? The query and it's results seem pretty fine to me.

Comment: There's no problem with that query. The problem is actually with the one getting the countries' cooccurrences. (the query in the **EDIT#1** works fine, the previous doesn't)

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT a.country_code, b.country_code, count(*) cnt ........ GROUP BY a.country_code, b.country_code` ?

Comment: Just did. But it retrieves nothing.